# Efficient way to read large tab delimited txt file?

Tags: c#, file-io, csv

I have a tab delimited txt file with 500K records. I'm using the code below to read data to dataset. With 50K it works fine but 500K it gives "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

What is the more efficient way to read large tab delimited data?
Or how to resolve this issue? Please give me an example

```
public DataSet DataToDataSet(string fullpath, string file)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + file; // Read all the data
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection // Connection
                  ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fullpath + ";"
                   + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
    OleDbDataAdapter ole = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection); // Load the data into the adapter
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet(); // To hold the data
    ole.Fill(dataset); // Fill the dataset with the data from the adapter
    connection.Close(); // Close the connection
    connection.Dispose(); // Dispose of the connection
    ole.Dispose(); // Get rid of the adapter
    return dataset;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a stream approach with [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) - this way you will not load the whole file into memory in one go.

Comment: from your link "TextFieldParser thus is rendered a cumbersome and slow solution that may be best left alone in its hard-to-find namespace."

Comment: @hemp - I linked to show the usage in C#. When compared to `string.Split`, it _is_ indeed "a cumbersome and slow solution". But that doesn't make a fair comparison. The article doesn't offer any other parser as comparison.

Comment: @hemp: "cumbersome and slow" it might be. But it works, and avoids many of the problems you run into with hand-written delimited text file parsers. I'll take "cumbersome and slow, but works" over "fast and buggy" any day.

Answer (score 3):

You really want to enumerate the source file and process each line at a time. I use the following

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(this FileInfo file)
    {
        using (var stream = File.Open(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then for each line you can split it using tabs and process each line at a time. This keeps memory down really low for the parsing, you only use memory if the application needs it.

Comment: Much easier to just write `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("filename"))`. That does the same thing as your `EnumerateLines` method.

Comment: But File.ReadLines returns a string array. The version above returns a line at a time, not buffering the file in memory.

Comment: No, `File.ReadLines` returns an enumerator that reads the file one line at a time. `File.ReadAllLines` returns a string array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the TextReader?

```
  using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(YourFile))
  {
      string strLine = string.Empty;
      string[] arrColumns = null;
      while ((strLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
           arrColumns = strLine .Split('\t');
           // Start Fill Your DataSet or Whatever you wanna do with your data
      }
      tr.Close();
  }
```

Comment: And this will reduce the memory consumption how?

Comment: Also, this solution doesn't deal with quoted values to allow tab characters to appear within those values.

Answer (score 0):

I found [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/)

> The **FileHelpers** are a free and easy to use .NET library to import/export data from fixed length or delimited records in files, strings or streams.

Maybe it can help.